# Is it ok to totally rewrite somebody else question?

Tags: discussion, edits

I have spotted an user that is offering bounties on somebody else's questions, and then he totally rewrites the original questions to fit his needs (at least twice). The rewrites weren't to make them better, but to explain his use case in detail, totally changing the OP use cases.

See the revisions to check the level of changes he made
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36528894/revisions
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48217823/revisions

Both of them were unanswered, and one of them almost 2 years old.

Comment: Those edits look sketchy as hell, but I can't put my finger on it as I don't know that much about cross-platform development for Android. The questions definitely look to have been edited too much to retain their original meaning (how important is the "crosswalk-project" dependency and how important are those version-specific actions?). Perhaps the editor was getting question quality warnings, and circumvented having to ask new questions by this approach?

Comment: Just flag them.  A moderator can tell whether he is question-blocked and found a workaround.